# Using np.random.randint as fill_value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a `numpy` array, where each element is the amount of `1`s in another `numpy` array of size `x` created with `np.random.randint`.

```
>>> x = 10
>>> np.random.randint(2, size=x)
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
>>> sum(array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]))
5
```

and using it like this results in the same array being used, instead of generating a new random one each time

```
>>> np.full((5,), sum(np.random.randint(2, size=10)), dtype="int")
array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

How can I do this, or is there a better way to do this? I also tried the following

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(10)
>>> len(a[a < 0.5])
7
>>> np.full((5,), len(np.random.rand(10)[np.random.rand(10) < 0.5]), dtype="int")
array([7, 7, 7, 7, 7])
```

but as you can see that also resulted in the same numbers. The problem is that I don't want to use for loops, and instead find a way to do it quickly using `numpy`.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to have the other array and count the ones in there? Can't you just generate the random number for the target array directly using an appropriate distribution? So probably just generate an array by using the binomial distribution.

Comment: @languitar it's because I want to simulate a Galton board (imagine 0 means the ball goes left, 1 means the ball goes right).

Comment: Sure, but if your left/right decisions are basically independent coin tosses, then the result of counting on direction should basically be a sample drawn from the binomial distribution.

Comment: @languitar because it's part of an assignment. I wouldn't know how to do it with `np.random.binomial` anyway and this is what I've come up with instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could just generate a matrix which is `N` arrays each of size `x` made of random ints. Then sum over each array,

```
import numpy as np
x = 10
N = 5
a = np.sum(np.random.randint(2, size=[N,x]),0)
```

I'm fairly sure `np.full` is not what you want here as this is for array initialisation to a single value.

Comment: This sums the the amount of `1`s on the `i`th position of each array, but that's not what I want. I want to sum the amount of `1`s in each array.

Comment: `a = np.sum(np.random.randint(2, size=[N,x]),1)` then?

Answer (score 0):

Using the binomial distribution as discussed above:

```
In [13]: np.random.binomial(10, 0.5, 5)
Out[13]: array([7, 4, 6, 7, 4])
```

This assumes that there are 10 distinct left/right decisions, each having 0.5 probability.